# In-ear monitoring - will adding ambient mic help my monitor sound be less isolated

Tags: performing, live-sound, stage-setup

I'm an active church guitar player and I've been known about these IEMs for a long time but it wasn't until a few months ago I started using them. At first I was impressed how better you can hear the mix and how different it sounds from live audio with no IEMs, I actually like it.

One of the things I've noticed is, of course, there's no external feedback, which means you can't really listen to what's going on with the congregation in matters of are they responding well or not to the music, do I play more, do I stop. So that brings me to my question, will that be fixed if I use couple of ambient mics towards the congregation? Will that give my in-ear mix a close-like live not in-ear feeling?

Comment: How big is the building/congregation?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you're using IEMs (particularly if you're using them in BOTH ears) mixing in an audience mic is standard technique.

IEMs solve many problems.  But they put you even MORE at the mercy of the sound operator.   Some of the problems they solve can also be addressed by NOT PLAYING SO LOUD!

Comment: I have actually worked for sound guys that have a PreSonus mixer that the musician could access the mix from their phones with an app called QMix which gives them control of their own aux mix rather than the sound guy having to do it for them.

Comment: Yamaha, Mackie, and Behringer all have proprietary apps that allow each musician to control their mix (by connecting to the console via Wi-Fi).